# an identity regarding the summation

Tags: analysis, summation

Assuming necessary convergence, why does the following identity hold?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_n b_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} a_n b_k$$

Intuitively this is clear, but what's the formal justification?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the necessary convergence, the lefthand side is summing an infinite triangular array by rows and then adding the row sums, while the righthand side is summing the same array by columns and then adding the column sums.

Comment: yes, this is also my intuition. But is there any 'formal proof', or it follows from some theorem?

Comment: It’s just a matter of verifying that both sums range over all ordered pairs $\langle n,k\rangle$ such that $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, $k\in\Bbb N$, and $n>k$, and that each such ordered pair appears exactly once.

Comment: have you tried by induction on both indexes?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_kb_i$ and $T_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{k=i+1}^{n} a_kb_i$.

Now, it's true that

$$
S_1 = a_1b_0 = T_1
$$

Let's assume that $S_n=T_n$. Now,

$$
S_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_kb_i = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a_k b_i + \sum_{i=0}^n a_{n+1}b_i = S_n + \sum_{i=0}^n a_{n+1}b_i
$$
And

$$
T_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \sum_{k=i+1}^{n+1} a_kb_i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=i+1}^na_kb_i + \sum_{i=0}^na_{n+1}b_i = T_n + \sum_{i=0}^na_{n+1}b_i
$$
But we assumed $S_n=T_n$. Therefore, $S_{n+1}=T_{n+1}$, and thus $S_n=T_n$ for integer $n\geq1$.

And if it's true for all positive integers, then it's also true in the limit, $S_\infty=T_\infty$.

Note that the final statement, "if it's true for all positive integers, then it's also true in the limit", is only correct for situations where the summation is absolutely convergent. This arises due to the inner sums in $T_n$ depending on $n$. Having said this, I suspect that there aren't any cases where the summations are well-defined and fail to agree in the case of sums of the form provided in the question.

Comment: This argument doesn’t work as it stands. Define $c_{n,k}$ for $0\le k<n$ as follows: $c_{1,0}=0$; $c_{k+1,k}=-1$ for $k\ge 1$; $c_{k+3,k}=1$ for $k\ge 0$; and $c_{n,k}=0$ in all other cases. This $c_{n,k}$ isn’t a product $a_nb_k$ formed from two other sequences, but you can still define $S_m=\sum_{n=1}^m\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{n,k}$ and $T_m=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{n=k+1}^mc_{n,k}$ and show by induction on $m$ that $S_m=T_m$ for all $m\ge 1$. However, you can’t extend that to the infinite sum: $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_{n,k}=-1\ne 1=\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_{n>k}c_{n,k}\;.$$

Comment: "Assuming necessary convergence". The set of values you have provided are not universally convergent - that is, changing the order of summation changes the result. My proof requires that the limit properly exists.

Comment: Indeed. But your argument does not make clear just what notion of convergence is needed, and since the argument for the finite case is rather trivial, that’s a pretty serious omission.

Comment: Sure, but the question provided the assumption. I was just adhering to the question. But just to assuage your mind, I'll add a note that, if convergence isn't absolute, then the limit for $T_n$ may not behave itself.